# Somar todos os numeros impares dentro de um intervalo dado pelo usuario

Tags: javascript, html, funções, matemática

Bom dia, preciso fazer um programa que leia dois numeros dados pelo usuario, e calcule todos os numeros impares dentro desse intervalo, ignorando os numeros dados por ele.

Meu codigo ta assim por enquanto:

```
let valorA = document.getElementById("numeroA");
let valorB = document.getElementById('numeroB');
let resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");

function calculo(a, b) {

    a = Number(valorA.value);
    b = Number(valorB.value);

    let soma = 0;
    for (let i = a; i <= b; i++){
        if (i % 2 === 1){
            soma += i;
            resultado.innerHTML = soma;
        }
    }


};
```

Answer (score -2):

Sua função está funcionando adequadamente.

Removi os parâmetros pois, no seu exemplo, eles não estão sendo utilizados, pois os valores estão sendo lidos no DOM pela função.

Faltou penas vocẽ chamar (evocar) a mesma.

Tomei a liberdade de criar os campos em HTML para demonstrar o funcionamento.

```js
let valorA =  document.getElementById("numeroA");
let valorB =  document.getElementById("numeroB");
let resultado = document.getElementById("resultado");
let botao = document.getElementById("botao");

function calculo() { // <--- os parâmetros aqui não eram necessários pois não estão sendo utilizados

    a = parseInt(valorA.value);
    b = parseInt(valorB.value);

    let soma = 0;
    for (let i = a; i <= b; i++){
        if (i % 2 === 1){
            soma += i;
            resultado.innerHTML = soma;
        }
    }

};


botao.addEventListener('click', () => {
  calculo();
});
```

```html
<input id="numeroA" />
<input id="numeroB" />
<button id="botao">Calcular</button>
<div id="resultado"></div>
```